# Binary tree with C++11 smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, pointers

I'm trying to replace the use of raw pointers with smart pointers in my C++ code. The following bit is from my first attempt at a self-balancing binary tree, though there is nothing self-balancing at the moment. I am worried about some fundamental problems regarding the use of unique pointers.

```
template <typename K, typename D>
class rbtree {
    struct rbnode;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<rbnode> node_ptr;
    node_ptr root_;

    struct rbnode {
        node_ptr left, right;
        rbnode *parent;
        enum { Red, Black } color;
        D data;
        K key;
        rbnode(): 
            left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr), 
            color(Red), data(0), key(0) {}
        rbnode(K k, D d): 
            left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr), 
            color(Red), data(d), key(k) {}
        rbnode(K k, D d, rbnode *p): 
            left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(p), 
            color(Red), data(d), key(k) {}
    };

    node_ptr insert_(node_ptr& node, node_ptr& parent, K& key, D& data);
    public:

        bool insert(K& key, D& data);
        void dfs(std::function<void (K& key, D& data)> visitor);
};

template <typename K, typename D>
void rbtree<K, D>::dfs(std::function<void (K& key, D& data)> visitor) {
}

template <typename K, typename D>
typename rbtree<K, D>::node_ptr rbtree<K, D>::insert_(
        node_ptr& node, node_ptr& parent, K& key, D& data) {
    if (node == 0) { node = node_ptr(new rbnode(key, data, parent.get())); }
    if (key == node->key) { throw "Key exists!"; }
    if (key < node->key) {
        node->left = std::move(insert_(node->left, node, key, data));
    } else {
        node->right = std::move(insert_(node->right, node, key, data));
    }
    return std::move(node);
}

template <typename K, typename D>
bool rbtree<K, D>::insert(K& key, D& data) {
    root_ = std::move(insert_(root_, root_, key, data));
    root_->color = rbnode::Black;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two constructors are never used:

```
    rbnode(): 
        left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr), 
        color(Red), data(0), key(0) {}
    rbnode(K k, D d): 
        left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr), 
        color(Red), data(d), key(k) {}
```

I would remove them.

I don't see a use case for the first one (default constructor). But if you must have it then you probably don't want to use use `0` as the initializer for the key and value.

```
    // Note: This is one of the constructors I would remove.
    //       But I just wanted to comment on the ** => data(0) and key(0) <= **
    //       initialization. Because this means that Data and Key types
    //       need to be initializable with zero (which is very limiting).
    //
    rbnode() 
      : left(nullptr)
      , right(nullptr)
      , parent(nullptr) 
      , color(Red)
      , data()      // Use default constructor for user types.
      , key()       // And for POD types this is zero-initialization.
    {}
```

Don't like the test against '0' here:

```
if (node == 0)
```

Prefer testing against `nullptr`. Not sure I like the implicit conversion to pointer but if it works I am not going to argue against it (personally I would have called `get()` to get at the underlying pointer for testing).

You probably want to pass by `const reference` or `r-value` reference here:

```
bool rbtree<K, D>::insert(K& key, D& data)
```

Currently it can not be used by the common case:

```
rbtree<int, int>  x;
x.insert(5,6);   // Fails to compile.
                 // You can not pass references to tempories.
                 // Note: You can pass temporaries by const reference.
```

You don't need to use `std::move` here:

```
 node->left = std::move(insert_(node->left, node, key, data));
```

The function `std::move()` converts a named value to an r-value reference. The return value of a function is already an `r-value` reference (I hope I got that correct).

Comment: the `operator bool` is overloaded for smart pointers to allow them to be used in conditionals so you can replace it with `if(node)` no need to `get()`

Comment: @ratchetfreak: That's even better.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I missed something, it appears that `bool rbtree<K, D>::insert(K& key, D& data)` always returns `true`. It is quite misleading. If there is no way for this function to ever return anything but `true`, you could as well get rid of the `bool` return type.

Also, I propose a different approach than Loki's one for the default constructors of `rbnode`: you can use in-class members initializers for the default values:

```
struct rbnode
{
    node_ptr left { nullptr };
    node_ptr right { nullptr };
    rbnode *parent { nullptr };
    enum { Red, Black } color = Red;
    D data;
    K key;

    // Etc...
};
```

This way, your default constructor can be reduced to its simplest form:

```
rbnode() = default;
```

And the "default" values from the in-class member initializers will also be used to automatically initialize non-initialized members in the other constructors:

```
rbnode(K k, D d):
    data{d},
    key{k}
{}

rbnode(K k, D d, rbnode* p):
    parent{p},
    data{d},
    key{k}
{}
```

Note that I also used [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) for some of the in-class members initializers and for the constructor initialization list. List initialization can help to avoid some problems related to implicit narrowing conversions of values.